# How do I copy the entire literal text of a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, variables

I'm new to coding, so this may sound like a dumb question, but here:
`String yes = "Yes. ";`
`String no = "But no.";`
`String whole = yes + no;`
When you print whole, you get "Yes. But no."
`yes = "No."`
`String whole2 = whole`;
I want whole2's value to be "yes + no;" because the variable "yes" has been edited and I want it to display the new data. However, whole2 only gets "Yes. But no." Is there any way I can do this? If not, please describe another way that gets the result I prefer.

Comment: This is confusing - do you want to print `yes + no;` or the new yes+no?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading question. I want my output to look like "No. But no." Thank you for asking me to clarify.

Comment: In that case, I believe my answer is the most simplest. If that helps, please consider accepting :)

Comment: So changing the `yes` variable won't magically change the `whole` variable *after* it's been assigned. Just repeat the concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to do it is just to assign it to the same variables again.

For example:

```
String whole2 = yes + no;
```

It saves the hassle of creating redundant methods etc,.